# Get Salesforce Product List and Data

Tags: api, salesforce

Can I get salesforce product list using REST API?  Or can you provide better and easier way to get product list. Please help. Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `Product2` records can be queried through the REST API. Here's a sample query:

```
curl -H 'X-PrettyPrint: 1' \
-H 'Authorization: Bearer ##Session_Id##' \
https://ap4.salesforce.com/services/data/v42.0/query?q=SELECT+Id+FROM+Product2
```

Comment: thank you for the reply. I have an error  401 (Unauthorized). I just want to clarify, is the session id is the access token?

Comment: Basically they are the same. Technically the session id is what you get from a direct login through the ui or SOAP api login and the user permissions aren't limited except by the user's profile, permission sets, etc., but an access token is what you get from an Oauth login, and they can provide even less privileges than the user would normally have, depending on the connected app settings.

Comment: Ow it works now, I just change the ap4 to ap5. Thanks for the help